How does the Foundry Resource Queue allocate vCPUs to Spark jobs?
I would like to know how Foundry allocates vCPU resources in relation to the Resource Queue.
For example, a build with a resource configuration of DYNAMIC_ALLOCATION_MAX_16 shows 21 vCPUs allocated.
What is actually happening on the Foundry Resource Queue when this build runs?
Are 21 executors allocated, or 21 cores?
Why 21 rather than say, 16?
Is a fixed 21 vCPU count allocated off the queue, or are resources dynamically allocating/releasing behind the scenes?
The executor-related environment config looks like:



config
value




adaptiveExecutorEnabled
true


driverCores
1


dynamicAllocationEnabled
true


dynamicAllocationMaxExecutors
16


executorCores
2


executorRequestCores
1.2




The 16 represents the (maximum) number of executors, not the number of cores/vCPUs.
Each executor may have a number of cores, the default is 2, but this can be changed to 1 if you need more memory per task, or increased to something like 4 if you need less memory per task.
Note that this is only the number of vCPUs in the executors. There will be other vCPUs being used in the driver. There are also parameters like executorRequestCores that can affect the reserved vCPUs in the queue.
If a job is configured to run with a Spark profile that uses dynamic allocation, the amount of resources occupied by the job in the queue will be equal to the maximum number of dynamic executors. Dynamic allocation can still provide cost savings depending on the job's runtime compute requirements.
(I recommend you take a screenshot of your spark environment used in the job and update the question, so that it can be answered with certainty)

Thanks, I have updated the question with some config.
If executorRequestCores affects the number of vCPUs, I guess we get 21 from 16 (executors) * 1.2 (executorRequestCores) + 1 (driver), rounded up.
Why over-provision vCPU resources by 20% by default?
